# Is executing a sequence of Commands possible using ANT Exec task

Tags: ant, exec, task

In ANT Exec task. I need to cd into a folder (Windows OS) (eg: D:\Testrun) and execute a set of commands in a sequence which will be passed as parameters to the ant script. Is this possible ? Could anyone quote a sample example ? Could the results of the command execution be logged in a file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you wrap up the sequence of commands into a script (e.g. a `.bat` script)? You could pass parameters to the script from your ant task. You could direct the output of the script to a file using the `output` attribute of the [exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html).